# Problem with exploding text file, using file function

Tags: php, explode

```
function dailyStat(){
    $data = "";
    $currentTime = time();
    $file = file("data/pageStat.txt");
    foreach ($file as $row) {
        $row = trim($row);
        $values = explode("\t", $row);
        $loginTime = getTime($values[1], $values[2]);
        if ($currentTime - $loginTime <= 84000){
            $data.=$row;
        }
    }
    $stat = fopen("data/pageStat.txt", "w");
    fwrite($stat, $data);
    fclose($stat);
}

function getTime($givenDate, $givenTime){
    $date = explode(".", $givenDate);
    $time = explode(":", $givenTime);
    $hour = intval($time[0]);
    $minute = intval($time[1]);
    $second = intval($time[2]);
    $day = intval($date[0]);
    $month = intval($date[1]);
    $year = intval($date[2]);
    return mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year); }
```

Heloo, I have following problem. I want to make a stat page about visits by page on my website in last 24h, but I have problem. Every visit on any page is written in txt file. I showed two functions here, dailyStat() - it should show only visits in last 24 hours, and getTime() - it should find utc from time i txt file.

```
/biznews/index.php?page=index   05-06-2022  00:24:57    192.163.50.1
```

This is the exaple of one row in txt file, every column is separated by \t and every row is separated by \n. The problem is that I always get error Undefined array key 1, Undefined array key 2. But I know that those array keys exist because I exploded them. Can someone help, because I don't know what is happening. Note: all paths are correctly.

Comment: The date in the example line from your file uses `-` as separator, but you pass `.` as separator to your `explode()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This practice is highly unsecure and with a simple bot which makes some thousands of requests to your site your server and your hosting account would be banned and down because you can easily consume all inodes in the host file system.

Make a new file for every request is a bad bad bad idea.

Why don't you use Monolog or other package which is easy to use and have an almos perfect implementation of logging facilities.

Use composer and follow https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-libraries/

If you need to parse logs you could https://github.com/pulse00/monolog-parser